# ng select not working with parent div ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

If I am using exact text for comparison in `ng-init` or `ng-selected` then it works fine for eg. `ng-init="status='OPEN'"` but this is not working when I am using loop variable `data.status`. Any suggestion?

```
<div ng-repeat="user in filtered = userList | filter:search">
   <select ng-selected="{{user.status == item.id}}" ng-options="item.name for item in item track by item.id" ng-model="status" name="status">
   </select>
</div>

$scope.item = [
    {id: 'OPEN', name: 'OPEN'},
    {id: 'RESCHEDULE', name: 'RESCHEDULE'},
    {id: 'CANCEL', name: 'CANCEL'},
    {id: 'CLOSED', name: 'CLOSED'}
];
```

Comment: Your markup is wrong. You are repeating `<div>` elements, not options inside `<select>` element.

Comment: this is part of code I have added here. I need to repeat div and show selected value of <select>

Comment: @Observer <?php  foreach($var as $key=>$value) { ?> <select><option <?php 
 if($value['status']=='OPEN') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="OPEN"> OPEN </option></select> <?php } ?> This is the expected result but in angular js. is there any possibility to achive this in angular js?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what exactly it is you are trying to do, and I think you may be trying to do a lot in one go when you should break it down more. One things that does stand out is that you are using `ng-selected` wrong.

Firstly you don't need to wrap the conditional in handlebars `{{ }}`. (That implies a 2 way binding to a JavaScript object, and makes no sense in this context).

Secondly, the `ng-selected` directive can't be applied on a select element, only on an option element.

To do what I think you are trying to do (pre-select an option) depends on how you are working. Here are a couple of ways

**2 way binding**

Remember that the data that you are binding to with ng-model is bound with a [2 way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06) which means that the selection will match the underlying data. In this case you shouldn't need to do anything fancy in the template.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList">
    <select ng-options="item.name for item in itemList track by item.id" ng-model="user.selectedItem">
    </select>
</div>
```

Instead you just handle it in your controller:

```
//This shows a static example. Change to whatever is appropriate, probably in a for loop etc
$scope.userList[1].selectedItem = $scope.itemList[1]
```

**ng-repeat inside the select**

Alternatively you may want to take the approach of using `ng-repeat` inside your select element. This then allows you to specify the behaviour more closely on an option by option basis.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList">
    <select ng-model="user.selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-selected="user.status === item.id">
    </select>
</div>
```

(N.b. I have edited some of your variable names for clarity eg. changed 'item' to 'itemList')